# Binary column by combining categories?

Tags: r

I have a question! I know what do but I'm having a hard time when trying to start coding.

I need to create a binary column by combining categories A and B (Low Risk) into one category and all the remaining categories in another (High Risk).

Comment: `ifelse(x %in% c("A", "B"), "Low", "High")`

Comment: Thank you! I have a question A and B are in the same Low and C,D,E are High should I do ifelse(Lending %in c("A","B"), "Low", c("C","D,"E"), "High" ) does this make sense?

Comment: If the only categories possible are A, B, C, D, or E, than the code I provided above will work as intended.

Comment: Thank you @Phil! I'm getting these error and error saying that the argument "no" is missing when doing only ifelse(Lending %in c("A","B"), "Low")

Comment: As per the help page of `ifelse()`, the function takes 3 arguments: 1. the condition, 2. the output if the condition is true, 3. the output if the condition is false. If you want the outcome to be `NA` if it is false, provide `ifelse(x %in% c("A", "B"), "Low", NA)`.

Comment: awesome, thank you!